# Seaborn stripplot of datetime objects not working

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Following the first example from URL:
http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html
I am able to load the dataset called 'tips' and reproduce the stripplot showed. However this plot is not shown when applied to my pandas dataframe (called df) consisting of datetime objects. My df consists of 19300 rows and 7 columns, of which 2 columns are in the form of datetime objects (dates and times respectively). I would like to use the Python Seaborn package's stripplot function to visualize these two df columns together. My code reads as follows:

```
sns.stripplot(x=df['DATE'], y=df['TIME'], data=df);
```

And the output error reads as follows:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I have made sure to remove the header from the data columns before applying the plotting command.
Other failed attempts include (but not limited to)

```
sns.stripplot(x=df['DATE'], y=df['TIME']);
```

It is my guess that this error might be due to the datetype object nature of the column data types, and that this type must somehow be changed into either strings or integer values. Is this correct? And how might one proceed to accomplish this task?

To illustrate the df data, here is a working code which uses `matplotlib.pyplot (as plt)`

```
 ax1.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Events')
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just to illustrate the df data, here is a working code which uses matplotlib.pyplot (as plt):                                                                                                              
 ax1.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Events')           With this output:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cjtw4oudedy22v/M4_13_01_scatterplot.png?dl=0

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of writing new information as comment. When reporting about an error, you should provide a [mcve]. If you cannot reproduce the problem with generic data, you also need to provide your data as well. Also, you need to include the traceback of the error.

Comment: Try `sns.stripplot(x='DATE', y='TIME', data=df)`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately this did not work either. The following shows the typeerror and complete traceback, together with a print of the dataframe content. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yroa4x14t73y70o/traceback.rtf?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the following code to previous script:

```
x = df['DATE']
data = df['TIME']
y = data[1:len(x)]
x = x[1:len(x)]

s = []
for time in y:
    a = int(str(time).replace(':',''))
    s.append(a)

k = []
for date in x:
    a = str(date)
    k.append(a)

x = k 
y = s
```

stripplot worked:

```
sns.stripplot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also try to convert dates/times into seconds to plot them as numeric values:

```
dates = df.DATE
times = df.TIME

start_date = dates.min()
dates_as_seconds = dates.map(lambda d: (d - start_date).total_seconds())
times_as_seconds = times.map(lambda t: t.second + t.minute*60 + t.hour*3600)
ax = sns.stripplot(x=dates_as_seconds, y=times_as_seconds)
ax.set_xticklabels(dates)
ax.set_yticklabels(times)
```

Of course, data frame should be sorted by dates and times to match ticks and values.

Comment: Nice strategy! Thanks. My idea long term is to create time series plots with datetimes vs. integers (specific measurements of something). Your suggestion could probably also become handy in combining data into equally spaced datetime intervals before plotting the time series..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the variables name as input of x and y; not the data themselves. For example :

```
sns.stripplot(x="value", y="measurement", hue="species",
              data=iris, dodge=True, alpha=.25, zorder=1)
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/jitter_stripplot.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30019709)